# Simple code for showing image in webpage using pdo

Tags: pdo

I am making a website in which there is a admin panel for me to insert post that includes

```
  post_title,post_author_,post_image,post_content
```

As I install xampp with php 7 in it So i am using PDO for MySQL connection.
I am successfully created the connection and successfully retrieve my post_title,post_author but I need a code to retrieve the image that is stored in mysql to show in my webpage as my post_title and post_author are shown.I need a code for showing a image that is stored in MySQL to my web page.
I am a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0):

well, first you need to know what information is stored in your database. i assume it will be the image path. so if you want to display the image you'll need some html:

```
<img src="[*post_image*-replace this with your image param output]" />
```